# mostrar el numero de indice de un vector

Tags: c++, c

Quiero mostrar el numero de índice en que esta posicionada cierta información en un vector.
Hice un for para calcular cual es la persona que tiene la menor cantidad de hijos y cuantos son. Una vez que obtengo la menor cantidad de hijos, quiero decir quien es el que tiene menos. Por eso quiero mostrar el valor del p.

```
for(int p=1;p<=5;p++){
       if (vector_numeroDeHijos[p]<menorTotal) {
           menorTotal=vector_numeroDeHijos[p];
        }
}
```

Es decir, si yo le pongo a p un valor obtengo lo que está en esa posición del vector. 
Lo que quiero acá es obtener el valor de p (no lo que se encuentra ahí). Cómo puedo hacer?

Comment: Pese a que el código que has facilitado puede ser compilado tanto en `C` como en `C++`, las respuestas pueden variar según el lenguaje en el que estés compilando... decidete ¿La pregunta es `C` o `C++`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

crea una variable,la cual copie el valor de `p` cuando se cumpla el caso de `if`

```
int pos;//icionador
for(int p=1;p<=5;p++){
       if (vector_numeroDeHijos[p]<menorTotal) {
           menorTotal=vector_numeroDeHijos[p];
           pos = p;
        }
```

aunque te lo debo de preguntar.¿por que `p` es igual a `1` y no a `0`?

Answer (score 2):

Una forma habitual suele ser obteniendo el iterador al elemento deseado y luego calcular la distancia entre el principio de la serie y ese iterador:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{9, 4, 7, 2, 8, 3, 5}; // vector de enteros
    for(auto& i : v)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto i_min = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    auto pos = std::distance(std::begin(v), i_min);
    std::cout << "el menor es: " << *i_min
              << "\nde indice == " << pos << '\n';
}
```

Salida:

```
9 4 7 2 8 3 5
el menor es: 2
de indice == 3
```

Comment: Probe con lo que me dijsite. uso devc++ 5.11 y el código este no compila.  Se te ocurre alguna otra manera? Estuve buscando y no encontré solución

Comment: @happyperson Sí, acá hay una lista de compiladores gratuitos actuales: https://isocpp.org/get-started

Comment: @happyperson si no nos indicas qué error de compilación te encuentras, difícilmente podemos ayudarte a solucionarlo. Mi apuesta es que tu compilador no es C++11 o superior así que te estará fallando en las líneas que se usa `auto`.

Comment: @asdasdasd entiendo tu uso de `std::begin` y `std::end`, es más genérico... pero en este contexto en que sólo se usa `std::vector` yo personalmente usaría `std::vector::begin` y `std::vector::end` a no ser que [happyperson](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/12932/happyperson) esté usando un array estático, en ese caso no tenemos más remedio que usar las `begin` y `end` libres.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Sí, yo normalmente prefiero las funciones específicas del contenedor, pero como no sé el significado de "vector" en la pregunta, por las dudas use éstas (que son funcionalmente equivalentes).

Comment: @asdasdasd coincido contigo pues :) por cierto, acabo de caer en que tu código puede fallar en caso de que `v` sea un vector vacío... mas en el ejemplo concreto que has facilitado no es posible ;P

Answer (score 2):

Dado que la pregunta ha sido marcada [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) y [c](/questions/tagged/c), y siendo la respuesta de [asdasdasd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/20916/2742)  valida pero enfocada tan sólo en el lenguaje [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), añado la respuesta en lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c):

---

Mostrar el menor elemento de un arreglo requiere recorrerse el arreglo al completo y comparar el valor de cada posicion con la posicion cuyo valor sea el menor hasta el momento:

```
int main()
{
    int v[] = {9, 4, 7, 2, 8, 3, 5}; // vector de enteros
    unsigned menor = 0;

    for (unsigned indice = 1; indice < sizeof(v) / sizeof(*v); ++indice)
        menor = v[menor] < v[indice] ? menor : indice;

    printf("indice del menor elemento: %d", menor);
    return 0;
}
```

En el ejemplo he iniciado el indice `menor` para apuntar a la primera posición del arreglo `v` y he empezado a indizar el arreglo desde `1` para evitar comparar la primera posición contra si misma.